# Is there a way to give `bitcoin-cli` a different default conf directory instead of specifying it each time?

Tags: bitcoin-cli

I have changed the configuration directory for `bitcoind`.

However when I make a `bitcion-cli` request:

```
bitcoin-cli getblockcount
```

I get an error about RPC credentials using `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin/conf`

So for me to actually run the command with the correct config and authnetication cookie I have to specify the configuration directory explicitly **every time**. Is there a way to make it implicit?

```
bitcoin-cli -conf=/media/btc/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf getblockcount
581510
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case I would create an alias?

```
$ alias BCLI="bitcoin-cli -conf=/media/btc/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf"
$ BCLI getblockcount
```

On Windows you may use [doskey](https://superuser.com/a/560558).

Comment: It's also common practice to use the same name when using `alias` for setting default options: `alias bitcoin-cli="bitcoin-cli -conf...`. If one ever wants to call the non-alias command, it's just a matter of prefixing the command name with a backslash to prevent alias expansion: `$ \bitcoin-cli ...`